# Going from SQL database to CRUD (and getting there quickly)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm running VS2010, IIS7 w/ SQL Server 2008; programming a web application in C#.

So, I've got my database with all relationships carefully mapped; it has about 25 tables with 6 different schemas (e.g. `[Account]`, `[Customer]`, `[Product]`, `[Category]`, `[Vendor]`, etc).

What tools, methods, and architectures are commonly used to quickly go from database to CRUD?

Comment: Why the vote close? As I see it, programmers who DO NOT already know what tools, methods, and architectures are commonly used to quickly go from database to working UI would appreciate this question and find use in an answer.

Comment: I am guessing the issue is that "working UI" is an extremely broad area. If the scope was limited to a CRUD interface I could see the question generating some useful answers.

Comment: @David: I voted close based on the question being "overly broad." No worries though, 4 others still have to agree with me.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for the explanation. Question updated accordingly.

Comment: @Beth: Sarcasm noted and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)? It provides some scaffolding to create a CRUD interface. You still have to do some of the wiring, but it gets you more than halfway there.

Comment: Sure, why not? With this project I am open to doing things in ways I haven't done before. I'm watching Scott Hanselman's video on it now.

Comment: Hrm, are you talking about creating a new "Controller" which allows you to select if you want it to create the the CRUD methods?

Comment: Yes, that is it. When you create a controller, you can tell it to *Add action methods for Create, Update, Delete, and Details scenarios*. Once that is done, you can right-click in each action to create its view, telling it what Model object to use as the data type, and which CRUD action that view is for. At that point, most of the HTML coding is done for you, and some of the controller code as well.

Comment: Eh. I'm scrapping the MCV route for now. I just don't have time to learn it at the moment.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://www.screencast.com/users/RPawson/folders/MVC/media/1624e6e1-0586-4f7c-97e0-ad56868fe24e

Comment: Well, I've got a good grasp on MVC now. So, this after a couple months of not answering my questions I happy to say that I've been (mostly) converted to MVC.